# Do I still retain my own vision type while seeing through my familiar's eyes?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, vision-and-light

Suppose my familiar doesn't have darkvision, I have darkvision, and I use my action go see through my familiar's eyes.

Can I see into the darkness even though my familiar can't?

Furthermore, does it matter whether my darkvision is a racial trait or a magical effect like the *darkvision* spell or the Devil's Sight invocation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No

Per the Find Familiar [spell description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar):

> "...Additionally, as an action, you can **see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears** until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses."

You are using your familiar's senses (their eyes and ears). This is why many casters choose different forms for their familiar. Is it pitch black? Then summon a bat with 60ft Blindsight.

Comment: Casting _find familiar_ requires the caster to spend an hour (+10 minutes if cast as a ritual) burning 10 gp worth of components. It is often not feasible to change the familiar's form based on whether it is dark, foggy, or what have you.

Comment: @Miniman, why is it such a big leap? The caster is literally using the familiars eyes and ears. Imagine you're stuck at home so you send your friend to a concert so you can watch too. All you have is them holding a phone and Facetiming information to you. You are now reliant on their camera's video quality, constantly telling them where to look, how to hold the camera, and so on. You see through that lens, but only what the lens picks up. You hear only what the microphone picks up. You will lose a lot of context and so it's up to the DM to say whether to use the familiars or casters Insight.

Comment: It is already a separate question, actually: [Perception checks through a familiar's eyes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/perception-checks-through-a-familiars-eyes)

Comment: Since it wasn't tied to the question, I removed all mention of skill checks.