# Does casting Beast Sense on a creature with truesight let you see as if you had truesight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, special-senses

In D&D 5th Edition, if you use the Beast Sense spell on a creature with truesight, do you see as if you had truesight?

Comment: Very related: "[Do I still retain my own vision type while seeing through my familiar's eyes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143009)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It doesn't matter; there are no beasts with truesight

The spell [*beast sense*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beast-sense) (PHB, p. 217) says:

> You touch a willing **beast**. For the duration of the spell, you can use your action to see through the **beast’s** eyes and hear what it hears, and continue to do so until you use your action to return to your normal senses.

As you can see, the spell specifies that you cast the spell on a beast, meaning a creature with the beast type.

As it stands, there are [no officially released creature of type beast with truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=2&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-senses=4&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=).

### But what if there were?

If, let's say, your DM had homebrewed a creature that was a beast that *did* have truesight; this would work in the same way as a beast with darkvision.

Since you "see through the beast's eyes", you would gain the benefits of its senses, since you're using its senses to see. So, in answer to your question, yes, you would then effectively get to use their truesight whilst seeing though their eyes.

My take on this matches up with the consensus of this related question: [Do I still retain my own vision type while seeing through my familiar's eyes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143009/do-i-still-retain-my-own-vision-type-while-seeing-through-my-familiars-eyes/143010#143010) (thanks to Medix2 for finding that question, see the comment under the question).

Comment: There are currently no beasts which have truesight, but not only could they exist in the future, homebrew (as you mentioned) is to be considered, and the answer to the question is applicable in many additional scenarios such as with find familiar which is not restricted to beasts.

I wondered since truesight is more of a supernatural thing while darkvision is fairly natural.

Comment: @soxroxr Yes, there could be beasts with truesight in the future, which is why I wanted to add the second half of my answer (it would feel somewhat incomplete otherwise, like I've essentially dodged answering the question). Truesight does have more of a supernatural feel, I agree, but it's still considered a sense (_Monster Manual_, p. 9), and therefore seeing through the beast's eyes would still let you have the benefits of that or any other senses.

Comment: @soxroxr because Truesight is a supernatural sense, any official creature that has it would almost certainly be classified as a Monstrosity, not a Beast (which is reserved for natural creatures). Which basically means it's restricted to homebrew only. (The Beast type not having any special, encounter breaking abilities is one of the reasons it's much more easy to shapechange into one, or have other effects like this, that would become way more powerful if it'd work on supernatural beings.)

Comment: @Erik At least one (rather excessive) way of getting a beast truesight is through the [*true seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) spell

Comment: I think you should move the part about no beasts having truesight to the bottom. OP asked the question because they wanted to know the answer, clearly they have in some way encountered it. Telling them that it is unlikely to happen is at best a footnote.