# So Sharing Vision with Eyes of the Runekeeper does it work?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars, eldritch-invocations

So I basically in a game sharing vision via my familiar and I was assuming that the Eyes of the rune keeper allows the ability to Read all writing. If I'm sharing sense with my familiar am I still allowed to read all writing as the text pertains that it allows me to read and doesn't specify familiar senses, Or I just can't read via my familiar and only by my own eyes.

Comment: Related: "[Do I still retain my own vision type while seeing through my familiar's eyes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143009)"

Comment: Eyes of the rune keeper doesn't specify who does it just say can read all writing.
Wouldn't be any languages familiar knows I know or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

#### What we know

Eyes of the Rune Keeper is an [Eldritch Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) that states:

> You can read all writing.

And [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) is a spell that states:

> [...] Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses. [...]

---

#### Rules As Written? You can probably still read all writing

Following the Rules As Written, it is probably the case that you *can* still read all writing as you are still the one seeing things and nothing in Eyes of the Rune Keeper establishes any requirements for maintaining this reading ability. One of the shortest Eldritch Invocations, it simply allows you to read all writing and puts absolutely no requirements on that ability whatsoever.

---

#### The GM is free to decide otherwise

The Eldritch Invocation is called *Eyes* of the Rune Keeper after all and you *aren't* using your own eyes; in fact, you are literally blind with regard to your own senses.

There is certainly room for a GM to rule that you cannot read all writing while looking through a familiar's eyes. Ultimately, as with many things, whether or not the ability to read all writing is tied in any way to your own senses, is not clearly spelled out in the Eldritch Invocation and is up to the GM.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the DM and I had a chat about it and declared its quite alright, and mainly because the familiar also comes via the patron as well so the invocation would be allowed as it doesn't specify who it gives it to.